# Перерисовка изображения c#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Всем доброго времени. Вопрос такой : использую Graphics для рисовки нескольких контуров (формат PNG) на PictureBox. Каждый раз когда я нажимаю на RadioBtn изображение перерисовывается согласно рисунку, чей RadioBtn был нажат. Проблема в том, что перерисованные контуры мелькают пока держиться зажатой ЛКМ, потом исчезают. Я наверное какую то мелочь не там написал, но найти не могу. Собсно:

```
 try
        {
            Image fon=Image.FromFile($"styles/{selectedRadioButton_Text}.png");
            pbx_StylePic.BackgroundImage = fon;

            Graphics gr = pbx_StylePic.CreateGraphics();


            for (int i = 0; i < OrderData.Styles.Count; i++)
            {
                if (OrderData.Styles[i] != "")
                {
                    Image im = Image.FromFile($"styles/shirt/{OrderData.Styles[i]}.png");
                    gr.DrawImage(im, new Point(0, 0));
                }
            }
        }
```

Подскажите, где напутался? Спасибо!

Comment: Да WF. событие происходит при нажатии на радиокнопку. В принципе решение уже нашел : Refresh() пикчера

Comment: событие Click (ЛКМ)

Comment: перенес комментарии в ответ. Перенесите уточнения из комментариев в вопрос.

Comment: "мелочь" в том, что нужно рисовать в событии Paint (и использовать Graphics из его аргументов), а не каких-то левых событиях, тогда и проблем таких не будет

Comment: @VadimTagil это не всегда возможно, хотя отчасти я с вами согласен, но лишь отчасти, т.к. иногда проще и правильнее переопределить унаследованный OnPant, или, как тут, рисовать по необходимости. Все зависит... Паттерны поминать не буду, и без них тема холиварная.

Comment: Я не вижу никакой реальной необходимости рисовать вне событий Paint. То, что нарисовано таким образом, сотрется при первом же скрытии и повторном отображении окна. Если проблема в мерцании при частой перерисовки со стиранием фона, то нужно просто включить свойство DoubleBuffered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нажатии на радио кнопку происходит несколько событий, просто нужно использовать правильное. Используйте событие `CheckedChanged` вместо `Click`.

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
   if (rb.Checked)
   {
      //ваш код
   }
}
```

Срабатывать будет строго один раз при включении кнопки. При клике по включенной кнопке повторного выполнения не будет, при снятии выбора с кнопки тоже.

---

Вообще, по уму, вы не должны рисовать вручную. Я не знаю на чем именно вы там рисуете, а вы этого не написали, но я бы дела это по-другому:

- картинки кладем в ресурсы
- радио-кнопками выбираем нужное изображение из коллекции (по индексу или имени не суть)
- контрол отображающий картинку берет ее по этому имени/индексу в момент перерисовки в событии Paint или унаследованном переопределенном методе OnPaint если контрол не стандартный, а унаследованный.

Таким образом не придется ловить ошибки связанные с перерисовкой окна после сворачивания в трей, изменения размера и т.д.

Comment: комментарий по поводу минуса будет?

Comment: Если кнопка создается динамически, как правильно присвоить событие? Так : RB.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(onRBstyleClick) ?

Comment: @Сергей сразу после создания, вы же ее должны создать перед добавлением, вот в этот момент и привязываете обработчик

Comment: Ошибку пишет : Не удается преобразовать тип "System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler" в "System.EventHandler"

Comment: @Сергей задайте правильный тип обработчику, отладчик в помощь

Comment: если это EventHandler, то как присвоить обработчику метод? Ошибка : нет перегруженного метода, который соответствует EventHandler.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56543/discussion-between-rdorn-and-).

Answer (score -1):

```
             try
            {

            Graphics gr = pbx_StylePic.CreateGraphics();
            pbx_StylePic.Refresh();

            foreach (string s in OrderData.Styles)
            {
                if (s != "")
                {
                    Image im = Image.FromFile($"styles/shirt/{s}.png");
                    gr.DrawImage(im, new Point(0, 0));
                }
             }
          }
```